# Vue: why this simple v-for doesn't work: Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives vue/require-v-for-key error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this simple component that has a `person` with values that it should display:

**TestFor.vue**:

```
<template>
    <div v-for = "(value, key) in this.person">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>

</template>


<script scoped>
    export default {
        props: {
            person: {
                firstName: 'Bob',
                lastNmae: 'Andersen',
                age: 27
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

However I get the `Elements in iteration expect to have 'v-bind:key' directives  vue/require-v-for-key` error. Which shouldn't occur, because according to documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html my syntax is valid:

[image]

[This video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXQh4Mrnddw) also uses this syntax and it works fine for them. Why doesn't it work for me?

**EDIT**:

As people have said the `require-v-for-key` rule is a culprit. Is there any reason behind that rule or is it OK to just disable it?

I've added `"vue/require-v-for-key": "off"` to `package.json` and the original code seems to be working now. Am I good or should I enable that rule back? It just seems like an annoyance for no reason.

Comment: For one, the video tutorial uses `data`, and not `props` like you

Comment: @kerbH0lz Why does it make a difference for `v-for`?

Comment: other question, do you really need `this.person` instead of just `person`?

Comment: @Ifaruki Probably not, but in my quest to get rid of the error I wanted to hedge that it's not the lack of `this` that was causing it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define key per element of your list. in your case, it's quite trivial:

```
<div v-for = "(value, key) in this.person" :key='key'>
  {{key}} : {{value}}
</div>
```

Without the key, Vue is unable to link data to components created with v-for. Lack of key means that any modification of the object you iterated would destroy and recreate all the child components, which would bring a number of undesired side effects. Once the key is defined, when collection changes, vue will calculate key for each element, compare it with keys of existing children and act accordingly.

Comment: @kerbh0lz - I am not sure about this - this exception is thrown by linter and it is there for a very good reason. Do you have any links to support this?

Comment: Don't pass a constant string to the binding (`:key="'key'"`), pass the `key` itself: `:key="key"`

Comment: Yeah, no, might have been wrong there, I just played around with https://jsfiddle.net/n8Lm7x9v/6/ and using `props` doesn't work while using `data` does without the `:key`. I removed my comment, sorry ;)

Comment: @ZedHome `:key='key'` is not `:key="'key'"` though

Comment: @ZedHome - Pants on fire: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62466626/revisions. It was never there. :P

Comment: @parsecer - Just edited an answer to include this reason. :)

Comment: I added `"vue/require-v-for-key": "off"` to `package.json` and the original code seems to be working now. Am I good or should I enable that rule back? It just seems like an annoyance for no reason..

Comment: @parsecer - You are better off with this rule in place. Lack of key can really spoil your day, as it can be quite tricky to debug. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State

Comment: Could you maybe add an example - pseudocode would be OK - of the undesired effects? I find it hard to wrap my mind over. For instance, if I were to change a `firstName` here, nothing bad would happen, because there are no child elements? But if the `firstName` had nested JSON objects or something then it would break things?

Comment: As mentioned in docs, "_It is recommended to provide a `key` attribute with `v-for` whenever possible, unless the iterated DOM content is simple, or you are intentionally relying on the default behavior for performance gains._"

Comment: If you change `firstName` without the key, Vue is unable to tell which child element this change refers, so it will destroy *all* children and re-iterate again through all the elements. In this particular case, this would not be a massive problem, but it is always best practice to include the key in you v-for iteration

Comment: Even if you have a very good reason not to have a key, I would not disable global linter. Instead you can add linter magic comment `<!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/require-v-for-key -->` with justification why it should work without the key. It is usually simpler to just put the key in though.

Answer (score 3):

The error is coming from your linter rule: [require-v-for-key](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/require-v-for-key.html)

You can fix it, with adding the key binding:

```
<div v-for = "(value, key) in this.person" :key="key">
   {{key}} : {{value}}
</div>
```

Comment: Why was this rule created in the first place? What's the benefit of it? The link you included didn't explain it...

Comment: It is mentioned in the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State These simple examples are working fine without a key, but the linter is also used to make it a habit, so later on you will not get errors that are hard to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The error means you need to bind the key property at your div.

```
<template>
    <div v-for = "(value, key) in person" :key="key">
        {{key}} : {{value}}
    </div>

</template>


<script scoped>
    export default {
        props: {
            person : {
               type : Object,
               default : function(){

                   return {
                      firstName: 'Bob',
                      lastNmae: 'Andersen',
                      age: 27
                   }
                }
               }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why does the error happen if according to documentations **it's not supposed to happen**?

Comment: See my answer. You have a linter configured to throw the error.